# How to handle the screen wrap repeat of FFT-based bloom effect?

Tags: image-processing, fft, post-processing, bloom

I am currently working on the FFT-based bloom effect. With the help of [a paper from GPU Gems](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter48.html), it works fine.

But it turned out that if the sparse point is near the edge of the screen, the bloom effect would wrap on the screen like this:

[image: wrap effect]

How to handle this please?

Comment: By making sure that the sparse point is never on an edge, or more precisely never on an edge you care about. I.e. simply double the size of the input image (by replicating horizontally & vertically), and crop away the extra area after processing.

Comment: No... Actually the sparse point is not on the edge. It still got 40 pixels away from the edge.@SleuthEye

Comment: Same applies if the sparse point is near an edge, so long as the bloom is less than the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want circular convolution artifacts, then pad the data on the 4 edges by the width & height of the effect before applying the effect.  Remove the padded areas after.  Zero-pading and mirroring the image are common padding choices.